# Inlining Svelte CSS in final Parcel build without duplicates

Tags: css, svelte, parcel, inline-styles

I'm using Svelte with Parcel v2. I want Parcel to build my Svelte code — including CSS and JS — into one `index.html` file, but currently it's building an `index.html` and a separate `index.css` file. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="svelte-embed"></div>
<script type="module">
    import "./script.js";
</script>
```

JS:

```
import App from "./App.svelte";

new App({ target: document.getElementById("svelte-embed") });
```

Svelte:

```
<h1>im in svelte</h1>

<style>
    h1 { color: red; }
</style>
```

.svelterc:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "css": "injected"
    }
}
```

There's currently [no official Svelte transformer](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7503) for Parcel v2. There are two third-party transformers out there: https://github.com/orlov-vo/parcel-transformer-svelte and https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-transformer-svelte3-plus. I've tried both and only the second seems to be picking up my Svelte compiler option. But once I inline the CSS in the final Parcel build, it still generates a separate `index.css` that gets linked in a `<link>`.

Comment: Svelte doesn't seem to mention .svelterc anywhere.  Where are you getting advice on its usage?  Is it a Parcel-specific thing or something?

Comment: Oh, and FYI:  According to Svelte's doc, 'injected' bundles the JS with the CSS, not with the HTML.  Just in case this is important to you.

Comment: Hi José! The transformers I linked say to I can configure the Svelte compiler via svelterc, svelte.config.js, or a package key — this might be a Parcel/bundler specific thing. Also… it actually seems like CSS IS injected into the HTML (and compilerOptions.css = "external" makes it not be injected into the HTML). But it also links a stylesheet duplicating the styles. Do you know why that might be? (Should I change the original question?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if you should change the question.  It seems that you may need to identify whether or not Parel has any part on this, and if not, I suppose then Svelte.